# Integrating Google Play Services C++ SDK into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-ndk, google-play-services, cocos2d-x

I have tried the following official guide here:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/gettingStartedAndroid

Which explains how to integrate gpg C++ SDK into Eclipse using ADT. ADT is no longer supported by google and I cant see why wouldn't they explain how to integrate it into android studio since they seem to keep it up to date?

In their samples here:
https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-android-basic-samples
They mention the fact that we need to use ndk r10e or earlier. Does that mean the latest NDK versions are incompatible with gpg C++SDK?

I however managed to get their samples compiled by a few modifications and changing my ndk version to 10 from what I had which was the latest 14. But then again I wasn't able to use their sample in my own game. I am using cocos2dx engine and no matter how much I tried to match gradle and .mk files it would not only fail, but also mess with the integrity of my build upon cocos2dx engine.

So what is the proper way of integrating gpg C++ SDK into android studio project which has a native environment already up and running? Where to place the content of the c++ sdk files and in what way should we alter the content of gradle and .mk files?

Answer (score 0):

Use SDKBOX. [SDKBOX Play](http://www.sdkbox.com/plugins/sdkboxplay) or [Google Play Game Services](http://www.sdkbox.com/plugins/googleplayservices), depending on the needs.

Comment: I just tried integrating sdkbox into my cocos2dx application in android studio with latest ndk version. It keeps crashing while executing ndk-build.cmd from the ndk bundle. (quite interestingly, i tried the exact same procedure last year and it had worked)